# Getting the ping results using java

Tags: java, jsp

I'm trying to get the last line of the ping result.
I'm not a java developer. I'm learning so please bear my mistakes.

This is the program I have written.

```
private static String pingTest(String ip) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String pingResult = "";
//  System.out.println("Came in pingTest");
    String pingCmd = "ping -c 3 " + ip;
    try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);                             
            pingResult += inputLine;
            }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return pingResult;
```

I'm getting the result as follows:

> PING google.com (74.125.236.165) 56(84) bytes of data.64 bytes from
>   maa03s16-in-f5.1e100.net (74.125.236.165): icmp_req=1 ttl=52 time=20.5
>   ms64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f5.1e100.net (74.125.236.165): icmp_req=2
>   ttl=52 time=11.4 ms64 bytes from maa03s16-in-f5.1e100.net
>   (74.125.236.165): icmp_req=3 ttl=52 time=19.6 ms--- google.com ping
>   statistics ---3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time
>   2002msrtt min/avg/max/mdev = 11.494/17.252/20.579/4.089 m

Its ot properly formatted. how to add line breaks? 
Well. what I really want is something like this.

Only the last line.

```
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 20.774/20.962/21.085/0.135 ms
```

and I want to show the values of min,avg,max values in my jsp page. Please guide me.

Comment: If you have found the solution of your problem then post it as an answer and accept it, so that other users can know that this problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
pingResult += inputLine + "\n";
```

note that it's typical to use StringBuilder in such situations, no matter what perfomance impact is

Comment: I added pingResult += inputLine+ "\n"; Didn't help. :(

Answer (score 0):

Update:
I updated the code. Now I'm getting only last line as output.

```
private static String pingTest(String ip) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String pingResult = "";
//  System.out.println("Came in pingTest");
    String pingCmd = "ping -c 3 " + ip;
    try {
        Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process p = r.exec(pingCmd);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new
        InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            //System.out.println(inputLine);
            if (inputLine.contains("rtt"))
            pingResult += inputLine+ "\n";
            }
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return pingResult;

}
```

Thanks