# Pasing a line and getting values

Tags: java, jsp

I'm getting output line as this.

```
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.876/13.344/17.155/2.736 ms
```

I want to get/parse the result as

```
min = 10.876
avg = 13.344
max = 17.155
deviation = 2.736
```

And I want to show them in a jsp file. How can I do it?

Update;
Sorry guys. This is what I did. 
[Getting the ping results using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21796549/getting-the-ping-results-using-java)
[Result redirection not working with jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797526/result-redirection-not-working-with-jsp)

I was checking the following method for parsing.
http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs302/examples/Parsing/parseString.html
I'm new to this. Apologies.

Guys,

I have modified my program as follows.

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String ip = request.getParameter("ip"); 
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
//          out.println("The ip address is:"+ip+"\n");
            String result = pingTest(ip);
//          out.println(result);

            String[] split_result = result.split(" "); 
            String values = split_result[3];
            split_result = values.split("/");

            double min = Double.parseDouble(split_result[0]);
            double avg = Double.parseDouble(split_result[1]);
            double max = Double.parseDouble(split_result[2]);
            double deviation = Double.parseDouble(split_result[3]);

            request.setAttribute("result", result);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("Output.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }
```

But How I will forward it now?
I have to add more request.setattribute?
like

```
request.setAttribute("min", min);
request.setAttribute("avg", avg);
request.setAttribute("max", max);
request.setAttribute("deviation", deviation);
```

Comment: Not an appreciable question, you need to first show what have you tried so far.

Comment: Show some effort @Randeep

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the input is Java. To simply extract the values, you can do

```
    String str = "rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.876/13.344/17.155/2.736 ms";

    String[] strings = str.split(" "); // split string on spaces, 5 new strings
    str = strings[3]; // select the 4th of these strings

    strings = str.split("/"); // split again, this time on "/"

    double min = Double.parseDouble(strings[0]);
    double avg = Double.parseDouble(strings[1]);
    double max = Double.parseDouble(strings[2]);
    double deviation = Double.parseDouble(strings[3]);
```

Then remains to parse them as jsp and put them in a file. I hope this gets you started on the problem. (PS: I haven't put the code in a method, as I don't know exactly how you will be using it.)

Comment: Thanks a lot ArneHugo. I'm a system engineer. Not a developer. Wanted to create a site myself. New to Java/jsp/servlets. The problem is, from the servlet I'm forwarding the result.
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797526/result-redirection-not-working-with-jsp[link]

So should I do this in jsp page or should I do this first and pass the result to jsp. I'm not able to insert java code in jsp. Something else might need there.I'm checking.